AWS: CORS error in Spring boot + Angular app - on some computers
Elastic Beanstalk - I created environment with Corretto 17.
Uploaded JAR of my Spring Boot app.
UserController:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {
...
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public LoginResponse loginUser(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        return userService.loginUser(userDto);
    }

CORS configuration:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

...

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                        .requestMatchers(POST, "/api/register").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(GET, "/api/register/confirm**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(POST, "/api/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationConfig.authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(jsonWebTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Content-Type", "Accept"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}

Amazon S3 → Buckets → bucket with back-end → Permissions → Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS):
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]

In another bucket I installed front-end.
Angular, UserService:
export class UserService {
  private baseUrl = 'http://mybook.eu-north-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api';
...
  login(user: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.baseUrl}/login`, user);
  }

I tried with specific links in SecurityConfig and CORS config in s3 bucket.
I tried @CrossOrigin in contoller class.
Edit:
CORS when I try register or login - for the computer I work on (win10). But I tried on another computer (win7, same internet connection). And there is no CORS, I can register, I can log in. Everything works. Another computer - does not work. Phone - works.

Edit your question more clearly to describe the clients which work and those that do not work.  Use a browser where you can obtain the OPTIONS call that it makes and post the details.  Note if the hostname/protocol is different and if those machines that work/don't route traffic to the server in some different way.

The problem disappears when I disable browser add-ons. I wonder if maybe it's because the backend in Elastic Beanstalk doesn't have an SSL certificate.
